# Make Fivestar 7.x-2.2 mobile-friendly

Tags: mobile, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fivestar

I am using the Fivestar 2.2 module. Everything works fine, but voting on a touch screen doesn't: It is impossible to give 5 stars on a 5 star widget, even though it works perfectly on the desktop. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to provide a link.

Is there someone who already solved this? Drupal.org is not a help.

```
/**
* @file
*
* Fivestar JavaScript behaviors integration.
*/

/**
* Create a degradeable star rating interface out of a simple form structure.
*
* Originally based on the Star Rating jQuery plugin by Wil Stuckey:
* http://sandbox.wilstuckey.com/jquery-ratings/
*/
(function($){ // Create local scope.

Drupal.behaviors.fivestar = {
attach: function (context) {
$(context).find('div.fivestar-form-item').once('fivestar', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $container = $('<div class="fivestar-widget clearfix"></div>');
  var $select = $('select', $this);

  // Setup the cancel button
  var $cancel = $('option[value="0"]', $this);
  if ($cancel.length) {
    $('<div class="cancel"><a href="#0" title="' + $cancel.text() + '">' + $cancel.text() + '</a></div>')
      .appendTo($container);
  }

  // Setup the rating buttons
  var $options = $('option', $this).not('[value="-"], [value="0"]');
  var index = -1;
  $options.each(function(i, element) {
    var classes = 'star-' + (i+1);
    classes += (i + 1) % 2 == 0 ? ' even' : ' odd';
    classes += i == 0 ? ' star-first' : '';
    classes += i + 1 == $options.length ? ' star-last' : '';
    $('<div class="star"><a href="#' + element.value + '" title="' + element.text + '">' + element.text + '</a></div>')
      .addClass(classes)
      .appendTo($container);
    if (element.value == $select.val()) {
      index = i + 1;
    }
  });

  if (index != -1) {
    $container.find('.star').slice(0, index).addClass('on');
  }
  $container.addClass('fivestar-widget-' + ($options.length));
  $container.find('a')
    .bind('click', $this, Drupal.behaviors.fivestar.rate)
    .bind('mouseover', $this, Drupal.behaviors.fivestar.hover);

  $container.bind('mouseover mouseout', $this, Drupal.behaviors.fivestar.hover);

  // Attach the new widget and hide the existing widget.
  $select.after($container).css('display', 'none');

  // Allow other modules to modify the widget.
  Drupal.attachBehaviors($this);
});
},
rate: function(event) {
var $this = $(this);
var $widget = event.data;
var value = this.hash.replace('#', '');
$('select', $widget).val(value).change();
var $this_star = (value == 0) ? $this.parent().parent().find('.star') : 
$this.closest('.star');
$this_star.prevAll('.star').andSelf().addClass('on');
$this_star.nextAll('.star').removeClass('on');
if(value==0){
  $this_star.removeClass('on');
}

event.preventDefault();
},
hover: function(event) {
var $this = $(this);
var $widget = event.data;
var $target = $(event.target);
var $stars = $('.star', $this);

if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
  var index = $stars.index($target.parent());
  $stars.each(function(i, element) {
    if (i <= index) {
      $(element).addClass('hover');
    } else {
      $(element).removeClass('hover');
    }
  });
} else {
  $stars.removeClass('hover');
}
}
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it's not what you asked but I'll try to help. Don't use fivestar, I've been in the same situation. I suggest you to try the rate module (https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) which is in my opinion a more complete solution.

I have a responsive website which of course works with mobile devices and you can vote without problem, although I can't assure it was mobile ready.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a chance :)